# Import data with 'Consecutive/Sequential GETs'

Tags: angular, rest

Hello, I'm beginner to Angular and I'm making an application that imports data from a government API regarding of beneficiaries of a social assistance program.

To get the API data, I need to pass as a parameter in the URL a date (in YYYYMM format) and the code in the municipality on the IBGE website, follows the example of how the URL looks:

`http://www.transparencia.gov.br/api-de-dados/bolsa-familia-por-municipio?mesAno=201908&codigoIbge=3509502&pagina=1`

This test code corresponds to the city of Campinas(in Brazil) and the month of August/ 2019.

Response:

```html
[
    {
        "id": 30204445,
        "dataReferencia": "01/05/2018",
        "municipio": {
            "codigoIBGE": "3509502",
            "nomeIBGE": "CAMPINAS",
            "pais": "BRASIL",
            "uf": {
                "sigla": "SP",
                "nome": "SÃO PAULO"
            }
        },
        "tipo": {
            "id": 1,
            "descricao": "Bolsa Família",
            "descricaoDetalhada": "Bolsa Família"
        },
        "valor": 5921632,
        "quantidadeBeneficiados": 34741
    }
]
```

Among the many values he returns, what matters to me right now is the value (valor) and number of beneficiaries (quantidade de beneficiários).

But what I need (and I come to ask you for help) is to make some script that runs this URL 12 times, or some foreach, and each time the month is changed, so in the end I get the values and amount of beneficiaries of the last 12 months. (I hope I can explain correctly).

Later I will take these values and make a graph. Can you tell me how I can get the last 12 months data from the selected municipality?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use forkJoin from RxJs and then pass the month/index to your dynamically generated url 12 times I am creating a sequential array which you can map to the request.

```
forkJoin( [ ...Array(N).keys() ]
  .map(index => this.httpClient.get(`http://www.transparencia.gov.br/api-de-dados/bolsa-familia-por-municipio?mesAno=201908&codigoIbge=3509502&pagina=${index}`))
).subscribe(responses => {
  // do your thing with response[0], response[1] and so on ...
});
```

Hope it helps

---

You need a function that can generate this information for you.

Note: this will return for 13 months 201908 - 201808. If you want for a year adjust the loop 0 - 12

```
function getAllMonthlyInfo() {
  const date = new Date();
  const months = [];
  for (let i = 0; i <=12; i++) {
    date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1);
    months.push(date.getFullYear()+ String(date.getMonth()+1).padStart(2,'0') );
  }
  return months.map(month => this.httpClient.get(`http://www.transparencia.gov.br/api-de-dados/bolsa-familia-por-municipio?mesAno=${month}&codigoIbge=3509502&pagina=1`));
}
```

then you can call this function like this.

```
forkJoin( getAllMonthlyInfo() ).subscribe(responses => {
  // do your thing with response[0], response[1] and so on ...
});
```

Comment: Hello Joy, In my case, the value of the variable I need to change is 'mesAno', should I put this $ {index} in place of 201908? Thanks

Comment: do you need to be for the year and month. then you have to work it up a little since index will only give you 0 , 1 2 ... but you need 201901 201902 etc how do you need them? last year from today or jan - dec?

Comment: I need to get the information from the last 12 months, as the current month (September) is not over yet, I get the information from August/2019 to August/2018